# "GNOME Disks" not showing all disks

Tags: disk-utility, gnome-disk-utility

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I have plugged an HDD into my Ubuntu machine through a SATA to USB 3.0 adapter a few days ago. This HDD is formatted with NTFS, its label is "D HDD" and it has some data on it.

This disk is listed by `blkid` (`/dev/sdk1`) and `/proc/mounts` shows a path that points to a location where I can see the files (`/media/warden/D HDD`, which indicates that it got automatically mounted there).
[Console commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTgGJ.png)
Even the Explorer-equivalent finds the drive and I can see its files:
[Explorer-thingie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPg13.png)
So far so good.
But: A program called "Disks" is supposed to show all disks that are attached to the machine. It finds all other disks that are currently attached but it does not find `/dev/sdk1`.
[Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y4ia.png)
None of the disks in that list are `/dev/sdk*`. All other disk are properly found. (`/dev/sdj2` as a random example.)

Why?

Interesting point:
The Explorer-thingie also shows another drive with the same label. It claims that its mount point is at `/media/nas/D Temp D HDD`.
[Explorer-thingie 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgvKS.png)
That's actually where it should be according to my script:
`mount -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 -U C20A3F620A3F52A1 "/media/nas/D Temp D HDD"`
But opening that folder and doing `ls -la` gives "Input/output error":
[Input/output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TNGY.png)
But I'm actually not sure whether I ran that script when I plugged the HDD in.
So this might be connected to the problem but I am, for now, just concerned about the fact that the Disks program does not show all disks.

Comment: Pictures of text are harder to read than text within your question so I gave up looking quickly, but a updated *bionic* or 18.04 system will report itself as 18.04.5 currently so your system is *years* behind on upgrades/fixes if it's still 18.04.1 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/02/15/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 18.04.2, but installed systems upgraded before this date)

Comment: Should I copy the entire console output into my post?

Comment: Most common issue is Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag & then Linux NTFS driver will not normally mount read/write to prevent damage. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation I also changed to not use spaces when I first started using Linux. I use CamelCase, under_score, or justaname for mounts or labels. I do also prefer to label all partitions so a default mount uses label.

Comment: It's not a bootable disk and it was not plugged into a Windows machine for a very long time (and if it was, it would not have been plugged in across a shutdown/reboot). Does the problem with fast boot affect non-bootable disks? I don't have the console output from the mount command anymore, but I would have noticed if there was that specific error, so I assume that's not it.